# Is it possible for an attacker to exploit contracts that rely on incoming "msg.value"?

Tags: solidity, ether, security, contract-debugging, vulnerability

I am developing an eth2.0 fuzzer for my masters that has produced some interesting crashes - if these crashes are legitimate I believe I *may* have found a new vulnerability - otherwise, I still have a lot of work to do...

My question is - Is it possible for an attacker to exploit the `msg.value` field (or any message data fields)? Particularly I am interested if this is possible to achieve in memory.

I have identified a contract that relies on the incoming `msg.value` and am wondering if an attacker could send say **0 ETH** to the external function of the vulnerable contract... while somehow altering the value of `msg.value` (to say **100 ETH**) in the receiving contract's memory?

**Example:**

**Vulnerable Contract:**

```
contract Vulnerable {
  function transferOut(address sendTo) {
    sendTo.send(msg.value);
  }
}
```

**Attacker contract:**

```
contract Attack {
  function exploit(address vulnerableAddress) {
    call.transferOut(<attacker address>) {
      <somehow send 0 ETH, but set the recieving ETH in memory to 100 ETH>   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to why it is not possible?

Comment: The `msg.value` is part of the signed transaction. When a transaction is executed as part of the block the miner has to make sure the sender has enough funds to cover value + tx fees. The manipulation of `msg.value` and account balances are handled by the client code (geth, parity, besu, etc). Any balance change in the EVM goes through CALL opcode family, those opcodes have invariants that forbid ether creation from the thin air.

Comment: On the other hand `msg.value` cannot be modified from the EVM. To modify it you have to escape from the EVM which is very unlikely. Perhaps you can exploit one miner to achieve this, but you cannot modify all of them at the same time. If a significant portion of network clients detect a missbehavior it is very likely the block will be discarded and the attacking transaction ignored.